# How to extract a particular link from a site if it has two links one which I want and other which I don't want?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```html
<td>
  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlstCollege$ctl01$hdnInstituteId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hdnInstituteId_1" value="866  " />
  <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_1" href="CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=866  ">A.N.A INSTITUTE OF PHARMACEUTICAL SCIENCES & RESEARCH,BAREILLY (866)</a>

  <br />
  <b>Location:</b>
  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblAddress_1">13.5 km Bareilly - Delhi road, near rubber factory agras road ,Bareilly</span>

  <br />
  <b>Course:</b>
  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblCourse_1">B.Pharm,</span>
  <br />
  <b>Category:</b>
  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblInstituteType_1">Private</span>
  <br />
  <b>Web Address:</b>

  <a id="lnkBtnWebURL" href='' target="_blank"></a>
  <br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlstCollege$ctl02$hdnInstituteId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hdnInstituteId_2" value="486  " />
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_2" href="CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=486  ">A.N.A.COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING & MANAGEMENT,BAREILLY (486)</a>

    <br />
    <b>Location:</b>
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblAddress_2">13.5 Km. NH-24, Bareilly-Delhi Highway, Near Rubber Factory, Bareilly</span>

    <br />
    <b>Course:</b>
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblCourse_2">B.Tech,M.Tech,</span>
    <br />
    <b>Category:</b>
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblInstituteType_2">Private</span>
    <br />
    <b>Web Address:</b>

    <a id="lnkBtnWebURL" href='http://www.anacollege.org/index.html' target="_blank">http://www.anacollege.org/index.html</a>
    <br />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract a particular URL(for eg: CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=866) from this website but this code has two  tags one of which I don't want(for eg:http://www.anacollege.org/index.html).

```
res = requests.get('https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeList.aspx?City=&CType=&Cu=&Br=&Inst=&IType=')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find("table", attrs = {'class':'table table-bordered table-responsive'})

pagelink = []
for anchor in table.findAll('a')[1:]:
        link = anchor['href']
        print(link)
        url = 'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/'+ link
        pagelink.append(url)
print(pagelinks)
```

I wrote this code but it is extracting all the links

```
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=486  
http://www.anacollege.org/index.html
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=602  
http://www.aashlarbschool.com
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=032  
http://www.abes.ac.in
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=290  
http://www.abesit.in
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=913  
http://www.abesitpharmacy.in
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=643  
http://www.vitsald.com
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=1036 
http://www.abss.edu.in
```

how do I solve this I only want the link with the CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=? part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor elements which are links to view college details have an `id` attribute which starts with `ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_`. So pass that as a [regex to the `attrs` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) of `find_all()`:

```
import re

for anchor in table.findAll('a', attrs={"id": re.compile("^ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_.*")}):
    ...
```

You can also just pass that as an [`id` keyword argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) to `find_all()`:

```
for anchor in table.findAll('a', id=re.compile("^ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_.*")):
    ...
```

The regex can be made even more specific, like `"^ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_.*"` which should only match the link provided with the college's name.

(I would remove the `[1:]` you put at the end since this probably filters out the link at the start you didn't want. If it doesn't, then add it back in.)

Comment: And use the newer/more standard [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) instead of `findAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `selector` and use it to find all link `a[href*=CollegeDetailedInformation]` Whatever you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeList.aspx?City=&CType=&Cu=&Br=&Inst=&IType=')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find("table", attrs = {'class':'table table-bordered table-responsive'})

allAnchor = table.select("a[href*=CollegeDetailedInformation]")

pagelink = []
for anchor  in allAnchor:
    link = anchor['href']
    # print(link)
    url = 'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/'+ link
    pagelink.append(url)

print(pagelink)
```

Output will be:

```
['https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=968  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=866  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=486  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=602  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=032  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=290  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=913  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=643  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=1036 ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=312  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=986  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=686  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=805  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=225  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=799  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=041  ',
'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=952  ',

and so on....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python but the general rule would be to populate an array in the for loop then do a lookup for a sub-string having your filter, pick the index and grab all that is in that index.

> Initialize and empty array outside loop (if empty is allowed in
>   Python), populate it in the loop, then do something like in_array (for
>   php) for your filter: CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=?.

This should be a good start as the masters of Python come on board to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet. Also install `**lxml**` library with pip before proceeding

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

es = rq.get('https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeList.aspx?City=&CType=&Cu=&Br=&Inst=&IType=')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("table", attrs = {'class':'table table-bordered table-responsive'})


links = [elem.strip() for anchor in table.findAll('a') for _,elem in anchor.attrs.items() if "=" in elem]

print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `a[id*="dlstCollege"]` to filter only links you want.

For example:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/CollegeList.aspx?City=&CType=&Cu=&Br=&Inst=&IType=')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find("table", attrs = {'class':'table table-bordered table-responsive'})

pagelink = []
for anchor in table.select('a[id*="dlstCollege"]')[1:]:
        link = anchor['href']
        print(link)
        url = 'https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/KYC/'+ link
        pagelink.append(url)
```

Prints:

```
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=866  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=486  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=602  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=032  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=290  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=913  
CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=643  

...and so on.
```